# Stack and Sets implementation (this vs var)

Tags: javascript, oop, data-structures, this, var

I was watching freeCodeCamps data structures and algorithms JavaScript implementations video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2CEgPsws3U) and I've noticed Stacks used `this` keyword (4:49) while their implementation of sets used `var` (10:06).

I tried to implement my own implementation of Sets and receive an error `TypeError: firstSet.forEach is not a function`.

1. Is this because I used `this` instead of `var` or did I make a mistake on the implementation?
2. Why did the stack implementation use `this` instead of `var`?

My Set implementation:

```
let mySet = function(){
  this.collection = [];

  this.has = (elem) =>{
    return (this.collection.indexOf(elem)!==-1)
  }

  this.values = ()=>{
    return this.collection;
  }

  this.add = (elem)=>{
    if(!this.has(elem)){
      this.collection.push(elem)
      return true;
    }
    return false
  }

  this.remove = (elem)=>{
    if(this.has(elem)){
      let idx = this.collection.indexOf(elem);
      this.collection.splice(idx,1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  this.size = ()=>{
    return this.collection.length;
  }

  this.union = (secondSet)=>{
    let unionSet = new mySet();
    let firstSet = this.collection.values();
    let second = secondSet.values();
    firstSet.forEach(function(e){
      unionSet.add(e);
    })
    second.forEach(function(e){
      unionSet.add(e)
    })
    return unionSet;
  }

  this.intersection = (secondSet)=>{
    let intersectionSet = new mySet();
    let firstSet = this.collection.values();
    let second = secondSet.values();
    firstSet.forEach(function(e){
      if(second.has(e)){
        intersectionSet.add(e);
      }
    })
    return intersectionSet;
  }

  this.difference = (secondSet)=>{
    let differenceSet = new mySet();
    let firstSet = this.collection.values();
    let second = secondSet.values();
    firstSet.forEach(function(e){
      if(!second.has(e)){
        differenceSet.add(e)
      }
    })
    return differenceSet;
  }

  this.subset = (secondSet)=>{
    let firstSet = this.collection.values();
    let second = secondSet.values();
    firstSet.every(function(e){
      if(second.has(e)){
        return true;
      }
    })
  }
}
let mySet1 = new mySet();
let mySet2 = new mySet();

mySet1.add(2)
mySet1.add(3)
mySet1.add(1)
mySet1.add(2)
mySet1.add(5)
mySet2.add(2)
mySet2.add(4);
mySet2.add(6);
console.log(mySet2.union(mySet1))
```

Comment: `this.collection.values();` -> `this.values();` or `this.collection`. Otherwise you're calling [`Array#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.collection` contains the array. Calling `Array.prototype.values` returns the [array iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values). Array iterators don't have a `forEach` method.

Just use `this.collection` instead of `this.collection.values`, and you'll be able to use `forEach` (referencing `Array.prototype.forEach`) on the result.

```js
let mySet = function(){
  this.collection = [];

  this.has = (elem) =>{
    return (this.collection.indexOf(elem)!==-1)
  }

  this.values = ()=>{
    return this.collection;
  }

  this.add = (elem)=>{
    if(!this.has(elem)){
      this.collection.push(elem)
      return true;
    }
    return false
  }

  this.remove = (elem)=>{
    if(this.has(elem)){
      let idx = this.collection.indexOf(elem);
      this.collection.splice(idx,1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  this.size = ()=>{
    return this.collection.length;
  }

  this.union = (secondSet)=>{
    let unionSet = new mySet();
    let firstSet = this.collection;
    let second = secondSet.values();
    firstSet.forEach(function(e){
      unionSet.add(e);
    })
    second.forEach(function(e){
      unionSet.add(e)
    })
    return unionSet;
  }

  this.intersection = (secondSet)=>{
    let intersectionSet = new mySet();
    let firstSet = this.collection.values();
    let second = secondSet.values();
    firstSet.forEach(function(e){
      if(second.has(e)){
        intersectionSet.add(e);
      }
    })
    return intersectionSet;
  }

  this.difference = (secondSet)=>{
    let differenceSet = new mySet();
    let firstSet = this.collection.values();
    let second = secondSet.values();
    firstSet.forEach(function(e){
      if(!second.has(e)){
        differenceSet.add(e)
      }
    })
    return differenceSet;
  }

  this.subset = (secondSet)=>{
    let firstSet = this.collection.values();
    let second = secondSet.values();
    firstSet.every(function(e){
      if(second.has(e)){
        return true;
      }
    })
  }
}
let mySet1 = new mySet();
let mySet2 = new mySet();

mySet1.add(2)
mySet1.add(3)
mySet1.add(1)
mySet1.add(2)
mySet1.add(5)
mySet2.add(2)
mySet2.add(4);
mySet2.add(6);
console.log(mySet2.union(mySet1).collection)
```

Or invoke the iterator.

```
for (const e of firstSet) {
```

Comment: _“Array iterators don't have a `forEach` method”_ — [yet](//github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers).